# streaming data into hbase using apache flume

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, bigdata, flume

I am trying to load data into hbase using apache flume. When I use flume for streaming data into hadoop, it works fine. But when I start the flume agent to load data into hbase I get NoClassDefFoundError.

```
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Reloading configuration file:agent4.conf
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Added sinks: sink1 Agent: agent4
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Processing:sink1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO conf.FlumeConfiguration: Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [agent4]
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Creating channels
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO channel.DefaultChannelFactory: Creating instance of channel channel1 type FILE
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Created channel channel1
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source source1, type exec
14/05/12 23:14:10 INFO sink.DefaultSinkFactory: Creating instance of sink: sink1, type: org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
14/05/12 23:14:10 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Failed to start agent because dependencies were not found in classpath. Error follows.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink.<init>(HBaseSink.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:415)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:103)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 17 more
```

This my flume conf:

**flume-env.sh**

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr
FLUME_CLASSPATH=/home/alpha/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib
HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/alpha/hbase-0.98.1/lib
HBASE_HOME=/home/alpha/hbase-0.98.1
FLUME_HOME=/home/alpha/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin
```

**agent4.conf**

```
# Name the components on this agent
agent4.sources = source1
agent4.sinks = sink1
agent4.channels = channel1

# Describe/configure source1
agent4.sources.source1.type = exec
agent4.sources.source1.command = tail -f /tmp/testGenerate.csv

# Describe sink1
agent4.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
agent4.sinks.sink1.table = AdreamLumiHB
agent4.sinks.sink1.columnFamily =lumiCF
agent4.sinks.sink1.batchSize=5000
agent4.sinks.sink1.serializer.regex = ^(\d+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),.*
agent4.sinks.sink1.serializer.regexIgnoreCase = true
agent4.sinks.sink1.serializer.colNames = id,nom,valeur,batiment,etage,piece

# Use a channel which buffers events to a file
agent4.channels.channel1.type = FILE 
agent4.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000000 
agent4.channels.channel1.checkpointInterval 30000
agent4.channels.channel1.maxFileSize = 2146435071
agent4.channels.channel1.capacity 10000000 

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
agent4.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent4.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you append the hbase classpath to flume?

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH=/home/alpha/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/\*:/home/alpha/hbase-0.98.1/lib/\*
```

Note: do NOT include the backslash before the asterisk *. I put it there because the asterisk is not showing up on this editor otherwise.

Comment: Just checking: are the hbase libraries installed on all of the worker nodes - and in the same loccations as shown in the properties files?

Comment: yes. I tried to merge hbase lib with flume lib but i get another error: ERROR hbase.HBaseSink: 
`Could not load table, AdreamLumiHB from HBase
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....`
And when I use a flume agent with AsyncHbaseSink i get this error :
`ERROR async.HBaseClient: The znode for the -ROOT- region doesn't exist!` 
whereas hbase is started properly.

Comment: Those errors seem more like configuration issues. Please ensure you are pointing your client to the correct hbase-site.xml and hbase-env.sh

Comment: I think my client is pointing to the correct hbase-site.xml and hbase-env.sh. When I use java program I can do put and get.it runs properly. I can post my hbase config if you want

Comment: Are you able to do a put in the **same** Java program as where you see the exceptions?  I am suspecting you need to add the hbase configuration directory to your classpath.

Comment: when I use a java client without using flume, I am able to put data properly but when i use a flume agent I still have the same error `ERROR async.HBaseClient: The znode for the -ROOT- region doesn't exist! `

Comment: Can you check what is the classpath being used by the flume agent? I have not used flume but it appears the agent is not getting the hbase configuration properly.

Comment: i think the flume path is good. I don't know why my flume agent is not getting the hbase configuration properly. I still have the same error: 
`ERROR async.HBaseClient: The znode for the -ROOT- region doesn't exist!
14/05/14 17:12:08 ERROR lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Unable to start SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@923288b counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Interrupted while waiting for Hbase Callbacks
 at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink.start(AsyncHBaseSink.java:379)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to copy all the jars from the /lib folder of hbase home to /lib folder of flume . This helped me in resolving this issue .